# Where could I find the setenv.cmd?

Tags: windows

Trying to build emerge(http://techbase.kde.org/Getting_Started/Build/Windows/emerge) with vc2008 expression, when I type "kdeenv.bat", the command prompt tell me that

**'"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bin\SetEnv.cmd"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bin\SetEnv.cmd" /x86**

After I navigate to the folder(C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bin), I find out that there is no "setenv.cmd". Where could I get this file?

PS: what I really need is the library of `openldap`; [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484788/compiling-openldap-using-visual-studio-10-express) suggests emerge

Comment: I am not entirely sure why this is tagged as c++ or c

Comment: It is only included with the full SDK version, not the trimmed A version that you get along with the VS2008 install.  Which doesn't need it since you already have the Visual Studio Command Prompt to configure the environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887894/how-to-find-windows-sdks-setenv-cmd-setenv-cmd-does-not-work-correctly) link.

Or you can write your own version of SetEnv.cmd and save it at **C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bin\SetEnv.cmd**. You can google for SetEnv.cmd script.

Comment: I solved the problem already by building the openldap package directly(by emerge openldap) without the build command suggested by the kde.